# How to close the tcp connection fully when using asyncio open_connection() when connected to server?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, tcpclient, streamreader, streamwriter

In the following code, the client opens connection to server using `asyncio.open_connection()`:

```
self.client_reader, self.client_writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
            self.host, 
            8080, 
            ssl = context)
```

And the client receives data using,

```
await asyncio.wait_for(self.client_reader.read(1024), timeout=10)
```

When the server is abruptly closed (Control + Z), doing `lsof -i:8080` on server returns

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-server-1:~/services/versionmgmt/tests$ lsof -i:8010
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    33180 ubuntu   21u  IPv4 339134      0t0  TCP *:8010 (LISTEN)
node    33180 ubuntu   22u  IPv4 339140      0t0  TCP ubuntu-server-1.internal.cloudapp.net:8010->117.195.170.225:64727 (ESTABLISHED)
```

It looks like I could see connection on server when `lsof` is used.

How to permanently close the connection from the client side. I have tried closing the write stream using

```
await self.client_writer.drain()
self.client_writer.close()                
await self.client_writer.wait_closed()
```

But the code blocks forever near `await self.client_writer.wait_closed()`, but why?

The connection is fully closed, only when the python client exits.

I checked the documentation to close read streams, but the connection didn't close.